# ¿estoy tratando de enviar el id de un tag a con ajax pero al recogerlo en php me retorna como null cual deberia de ser la manera correcta?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".vista_rapida").click(function() {
var vista_rapidas=$(this).attr("id");
         $.ajax({
          url:'aindex.php',
          method:'post',
          data:{"producto_indice":vista_rapidas}
          });
          });
           });
</script>

 <?
  $data =$_POST['producto_indice'];
   echo var_dump($data);
  ?>
```

Comment: ¿Te retorna `null` dónde? En jQuery no veo que manejes nada para el retorno. De todos modos, sería buena que pongas el código HTML donde está el elemento cuya clase es `vista_rapida`.

Answer (score 0):

Hace falta que coloques mas parte de tu código HTML, pero he modificado un poco tu código, asi que te voy a explicar lo que ha pasado :)

```
   var vista_rapidas=$(this).attr('name'); /*con esta linea capturas el valor que tiene tu 'input' */
        var parametros = {  
                "producto_indice" : vista_rapidas, /* con esta linea vas a crear una variable con el nombre vista_rapidas, el cual contendra el contenido del 'input' antes mencionado*/

                        };
        $.ajax({
                data:  parametros, //datos que se envian a traves de ajax
                url:   'aindex.php', //archivo que recibe la peticion
                type:  'post', //método de envio, puede ser GET
                beforeSend: function () {
                        //$("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor..."); /*esta parte es opcional, es para mostrar un mensaje en alguna parte de tu pagina hasta que el php procese la información que has enviado */
                },
                success:  function (response) { //una vez que el archivo recibe el request lo procesa y lo devuelve
                       $("#resultado").html(response); /*lo que podes hacer es poner la respuesta dentro de un div con id "resultado". */

                }
```

y tu php te quedaría igual :)

Podrías darle una revisada a la documentación que hay con respecto a mandar información a través de ajax, aquí en el foro hay temas relacionados :) saludos.